# Missing views in landscape / scrolling view

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, screen-orientation, android-scrollview

I have created a layout that have a header and scrolling body. I'm able to see the header in portrait mode, but when it entered landscape mode or I have to scroll it, the header was missing.

I wanted the header to stay static, only the body should be scrolled.
The left side is in portrait and the right-side is in landscape.

[image: sample image]

**main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_screenEdge"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <include layout="@layout/header_inspection"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_body"/>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_body.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:context="my.mimos.fssm.kpkt.layout.Lain2Generik">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/form_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/form_background">

            <LinearLayout...> //header

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 1

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 2

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 3

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 4

        </Linearlayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**header_inspection.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:dividerPadding="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
            android:text="@string/btn_sebelumnya"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_nxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
            android:text="@string/btn_seterusnya"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end">

        <TextView
            style="@style/marks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Markah : "/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cur_marks"
            style="@style/marks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your "header_inspection_view" is not showing here. Right?

Comment: @Ankita yes, my 'header_inspection' view is missing when in landscape. if I added the header to main activity, then the header would be scrolled along with it. I would prefer the header to stay static

Comment: Try to put your scrollview inside a linear layout and set match_parent property for both dimesion (height & width).

Comment: i would suggest you to use two pane in landscape your ui will look awesome in that way

Comment: @Ankita the issue still persist. The header still missing. Though I have found the solution for it. I should have include `layout_height` & `layout_width` inside `include` header.

Comment: @AdeelTurk thank you for suggesting. I have already created a two-pane landscape including the item list on the left side :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with it. Apparently I should have included the `layout_height` and `layout_width` in **include** tag. Therefore, the correct code for **main_activity** should be:

**main_body.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="@dimen/padding_screenEdge"
              tools:context="my.mimos.fssm.kpkt.layout.Lain2Generik">

    <include layout="@layout/header_inspection"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_lain2_generik"/>

    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
             tools:context="my.mimos.fssm.kpkt.layout.Lain2Generik">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/form_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/form_background">

            <LinearLayout...> //header
            <ScrollView                    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 1

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 2

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 3

            <LinearLayout...> //column item 4
</ScrollView>
        </Linearlayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> try to wrap the columns in side the scrollview and keep the header outside of scrollview